# macOS Sierra Server - Problems with permissions in shared folders

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, macos-sierra

I have a macOS Sierra with the Server package installed.

There are directories that when a user create/modify files or folders the others users has read only permissions. Only it happen in some directories.

I think that the problem is the umask. I would like to set umask at 011 with this I have read/write in all user/groups.

I have seen how do it but in other mac versions, yosemite, not in Sierra.

I need to apply mask only in a directory don't in all filesystem.

Do anybody help with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Ever since the introduction of Mac OS X introduced Unix-style ownership/permissions, dealing with ownership/permissions problems between Mac file servers and Mac clients has been a nightmare. The only way to make it manageable is to run an Open Directory server, define everyone's accounts in Open Directory, and force all your users to bind their client Macs to your Open Directory server and log into the GUI on their client Macs using their Open Directory accounts (not locally-defined macOS accounts). Also make sure all your Mac file servers are also bound to Open Directory.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a general consensus on directories having the permission of `755` while files to have the permission of `644`